# Cannot determine if text box is empty

Tags: ms-access, vba

This should be a simple and I have already done half an hour of forum reading, but for some reason I am missing something. I want to use VBA to see if a text box is empty. I made sure the text box was empty by using `Me.TxtBox.Value = Nothing`.

So far, here is what I have tried and the error messages I get:

---

`IsNull(Me.TxtBox.Value)` Returns: `False`

---

`IsNull(Me.TxtBox)` Returns: `False`

---

`Len(Me.TxtBox.Value & vbNullString)` Returns: `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

---

The entire form is unbounded, but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: Pleas show a bit more code. Setting a Value = Nothing is not going to help. Only Objects can be set to Nothing. Values need to be Null or Null String.

Comment: As @PaulFrancis says, it is `Me.TxtBox.Value = Nothing` that is causing the problem. You need `Me.TxtBox.Value = null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to make the text box empty:

```
Me.TxtBox = Null
```

to determine if text box is empty:

```
IsNull(Me.TxtBox)
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need to test whether the box is truly empty (null) or just contains a zero-length string:-

```
if len(trim(me.txtbox.value & vbnullstring)) = 0 then 
' it's empty
else
' it's not empty
end if
```

You can also use "" instead of vbnullstring.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was coming from. The problem was caused by setting `Me.TxtBox.Value = Nothing`. When I want to clear the value, if I use `Me.TxtBox.Value = vbNullString`, then I can check to see if the length is zero.

Thank you all for your help. I think in the future I will `Me.TxtBox = Null`. That seems like the simplest solution.